# Issue creating bottom-tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have created a login screen for my expo react-native app.  However, once the the user has logged in, at the home screen, I would like to show 3 icons at the bottom tab.But i am not sure how to create the bottom tabs.  Essentially, there will be 3 tabs that need to be created (e.g. calendar, activity and settings).

App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import LoginScreen from './screens/Dashboard/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/Dashboard/HomeScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>

  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

HomeScreen.js

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core'
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Image } from 'react-native'
import { auth } from '../../firebase'

const HomeScreen = () => {
const navigation = useNavigation()

const handleSignOut = () => {
    auth
    .signOut()
    .then(() => {
        navigation.replace("Login")
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error.message))
}

return (
    
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Email: {auth.currentUser?.email}</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={handleSignOut}
        style={styles.button}
    >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign out</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>    
)
}

export default HomeScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
},
button: {
    backgroundColor: '#0782F9',
    width: '60%',
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 40,
},
buttonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: '700',
    fontSize: 16,
},
image: {
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
},
})
```

Would appreciate your help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a component like shown in react navigation docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator/#example and then replace the "HomeScreen" component with the newly create Tabs navigator component.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={MyTabs} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>

  );
}


  [1]: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-bottom-tab-navigator
```